# Defining the function near some points.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

How we can show that ,

$$\ln(x+2y)+32x^3y^2=\frac{1}{4}$$

defines $y$ as a function of $x$ near the points $\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}\right)$ and calculate $y'(1/2).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Implicit function theorem
$$
F(x,y)=ln(x+2y)+32x^3y^2-\frac{1}{4}=0 \\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=\frac{2}{x+2y}+64x^3y\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4})\ne 0
$$
Therefore y defines a function of x.
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac{1+2y'}{x+2y}+96x^2y^2\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x=\frac{1}{2},y=\frac{1}{4})=0
$$
Insert $x,y$ and find $y'$